# Pass MotionEvent to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have activity with ViewPager that is filled with MyButtons that implements onTouch and sometimes that buttons take over move action and ViewPager does not know that he should move. How to pass MotionEvent to ViewPager?

below is some of my try

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements View.OnTouchListener {

private Context context;

public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        ((MainActivity) context).notifViewPager(event);

    //...

    return false;
}
}
```

MainActivity with ViewPager

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//...

ublic void notifViewPager(MotionEvent event) {
    Utils.PrintInfo("notifViewPager");
    mViewPager.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

//...

}
```

Comment: This [link](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) may help you

Comment: i dont know if it helped, but im sure it lead me to other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426291/onintercepttouchevent-lead-to-pointerindex-out-of-range